# Export csv in R

Tags: r

Try to export my data.frame to csv

```r
google_analytics(214199202,
                     date_range = c("2020-05-27", "2020-06-11"),
                     metrics = c("ga:transactions","ga:transactionRevenue"),
                     dimensions = c("ga:date","ga:campaign","ga:sourceMedium"),
                     filtersExpression = "ga:sourceMedium=~(yandex / cpc|google / cpc)",
                     write.csv(google_analytics, file = "filename.csv")
                     )
```

But after running it, I receive this error:

> **Ошибка в as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :   cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame**

I don't understand where the problem is

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `googleAnalyticsR` but from what I can see in the manual, `google_analytics()` returns a `data.frame` and the 6th argument is `met_filters`. You put the function `write.csv()` in the 6th argument as `met_filters` thus resulting in error. You should save the output of `google_analstics` first then export to csv.

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)

# Fetch data and save data.frame to "yourData"
yourData <- google_analytics(
  214199202,
  date_range = c("2020-05-27", "2020-06-11"),
  metrics = c("ga:transactions","ga:transactionRevenue"),
  dimensions = c("ga:date","ga:campaign","ga:sourceMedium"),
  filtersExpression = "ga:sourceMedium=~(yandex / cpc|google / cpc)"
)

# Export "yourData" as csv
write.csv(yourData, file = "filename.csv")
```